# IE8 not rendering SVG files correctly via SVGWeb plugin

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg, svgweb

I have an SVG that was produced in Adobe Illustrator.

I have pasted it directly into a page using the format

```
 <script type="image/svg+xml">
      // paste from <svg version="1.1"...
      // to </svg>
      // .AI files have an XML statement and DOCTYPE that I leave off
 </script>
```

the code then manages to render the image on page.

The problem is the IE8 version looks a little off.

Is there something I can do with respect to the right export settings that will tell IE8 to step up to the plate?

On thing I was thinking is that there may have been some sort of degradation since the designer saved it as SVG, then when I asked for changes to the file opened the SVG and re-saved (rather than exporting from the AI file which was the primary source).  **edit** this did not fix the issue.

I'll try that as my first line of defense - but if anyone has other suggestions, I would love to hear them.

I have also tried the AMPLE svg plugin as an alternative (with hilarious results, MUCH worse)

[image: SVG as seen in Chrome and IE8 rendered using SVGWEB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVGWeb does not support stroke-dasharray, that's why all dashes are showing up as solid lines. There is no export setting to account for this in Adobe Illustrator. The only alternative would be creating a separate element for each dash (I cringe thinking about this).

I'd suggest falling back to a bitmap .png.

Comment: I just sat down with the design guy and we looked at our options... one that we're just about to try is the "convert to outline" option on the whole document (a one-click version of making a separate element for each dash). I'll report back soon as the files come through :)